# Scala view bounds, what's wrong with my example

Tags: scala

I use the below example to strengthen understanding of Scala view bounds:

```
case class Person(age: Int)
object P003 {
implicit def m(p: Person) = new Ordering[Person] {
    override def compare(x: Person, y: Person): Int = {
    x.age - y.age
  }
}

def sort[T <% Ordering[T]](list: List[T]) = list.sorted

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val list = List(Person(10), Person(2), Person(8))
  println(sort(list))
}
```

but errors thrown out when compiled:

[image: Failure]

I can't find out why, appreciate if someone offer any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala View Bounds *was* a mechanism to allow you to view a type `A` as type `B`. In your example, it looks like you've mixed `Ordering[T]` with `Ordered[T]`. When a class implements `Ordered[T]` with an addition of view bounds, it allows you to view the `T` as `Ordered[T]`. With your example, it allows you to look at a `Person` as an `Ordered[Person]`, and provide that as an implicit order for `list.sort`.

This is what your class actually should of looked like:

```
case class Person(age: Int) extends Ordered[Person] {
  override def compare(that: Person): Int = this.age - that.age
}
```

And then:

```
object P003 {
  def sort[T <% Ordered[T]](list: List[T]) = list.sorted

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val list = List(Person(10), Person(2), Person(8))
    println(sort(list))
  }
}
```

Yields:

```
List(Person(2), Person(8), Person(10))
```

But, View Bounds was deprecated (there is a rather long discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/hNow9MvAi6Q/discussion) in regards to that). You can achieve the same with a Context Bound and `Ordering.by`:

```
case class Person(age: Int)

object P003 {
  implicit def personOrdering: Ordering[Person] = Ordering.by(p => p.age)

  def sort[T: Ordering](list: List[T]) = list.sorted

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val list = List(Person(10), Person(2), Person(8))
    println(sort(list))
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `def personOrdering`, not `val personOrdering`? Isn't it supposed to be immutable?

Comment: @VictorMoroz Not sure what immutability has to do with the fact it's a `def`? You're right it can be turned into a `val` to avoid allocations of `Ordering`.